# Angular2 Templates: How to bind keydown.arrow to whole div instead of only control elements?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a simple navigator component with some buttons and a date-picker subcomponent. Now the idea is, that I can bind `keydown.arrowleft` etc. for the whole div (which has css style of 100% height and width). It's template looks like this:

```
<div id="ck-navigator" (keydown.arrowleft)="decrementDate(); 
    $event.preventDefault()" (keydown.arrowright)="incrementDate(); 
$event.preventDefault()">
    <button (click)="decrementDate()" class="fa fa-2x fa-chevron-left">
    </button>
    <ck-date-picker [date]="date" (dateChange)="changeDate($event)">
    </ck-date-picker>
    <button (click)="incrementDate()" class="fa fa-2x fa-chevron-right"></button>
</div>
```

I don't show the component code, it does not matter for this question (afaik).
This is working, but only if I actively select a button or the date-picker in advance (aka a control element). Is there a possibility to extend the keybinding to the whole div (i.e. if I just click somewhere on the site). Sorry for my lack of understanding the DOM and thanks for any push in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want is to detect key events on the whole page what you need is probably to add @HostListener to your component. It is gona let you manage events in the whole page/window.

Seeing an example.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
```

[your @Component stuff ..... ]

```
@HostListener("window:keydown", ['$event'])

 onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent) {

    console.log(`Pressed ${event.key}!`);
  }
```

Furthermore could help you to know that when you want to refer specific items you can use ElementRef class and ViewChild by importing them from angular/core. Then manage DOM components as:

```
@ViewChild('DOM_Id') element: ElementRef;
```

Maybe it helps. Peace

Comment: Luca's answer was correct as my question was not clear. But your answer hits the nail! It's working smoothly. Now I finally have a (working) example of what to use @HostListener for inside of normal components. My book-example used it just for directives (as they have no template to be bound against).

Comment: I want to get events from a specific element. Not from the window. How could I do that? I couldn't understand how can I use @viewChild for this purpose?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that your div is not focusable so it isn't reacting to your keybindings. Try adding the attribute `tabindex="0"` to the div.

Comment: Thank you!! Was debugging for an hour until I came across your answer.