# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./BaPageTop class BaPageTop - inline template:49:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Tags: angular

after setting the focus its getting error like this in angular 2

i tried two types of code.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  document.getElementById(`myname`).focus();
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./BaPageTop class BaPageTop - inline template:49:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'focus' of null
```

Comment: using click event also i tried getting same error in our project

Comment: @SachnGowda I think you need to use viewChild and nativeElement.

Comment: Are you sure document.getElementById() accepts template quoting you using? `` Try to use single quotes instead ('myname') .

Comment: I found this I ve answer time ago and I think it fills your intention. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43158345/7733724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use different method which is `viewChild`
in `.html` file

```
<div (click)="toggleFocus()">Some Label</div>
<textarea #txtArea></textarea>
```

and in your class

```
constructor(){}
@ViewChild('txtArea' , {read: ElementRef}) input: ElementRef;
 toggleFocus() {
  this.input.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you referenced does not exists in your DOM in the moment the script is launched. 
It is a NullPointer. Check element ID reference and think about execution pipeline to notice if script could be being launched before the item is loaded.

If you use `ngAfterViewInit()` is supposed the element you reference by `document.getElementById` is inside your component, right?

Try to add "when" ngOnInit instead to do the try and I recommend you check the next link to understand [Angular Component Lifecycle Hooks](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-2-component-lifecycle-hooks-fa5a84b4b64d)